# Control for Selecting 'Yes', 'No' or 'All' and Pass to Query

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have a table that includes a 'Member / Non Member' field, with the type 'Yes / No'.

I have a form that will (among other things) print mailing labels, and I want to add a control that will allow it to print all labels by default, or only 'yes' (members) or only 'no' (non-members).

I can do the 'yes' or 'no' scenarios, but not the 'all'. I've tried tri-state checkboxes etc, but I'm unsure how to have the control tell the query 'Give me everything if nothing (or 'all') is selected, only members if 'yes' is selected, or only non-members if 'no' is selected'.

I feel a bit silly asking, but there you are :)

Cheers

R

Answer (score 0):

Try a combo, using a Value List, eg All;Yes;No.

You can then use that to Filter the form (or clear the Filter if 'All')

OR

use it to change the criteria of the query, eg:

```
dim s$
s = "SELECT MyQuery.* FROM MyQuery" & _
    iif(MyCombo<>"All"," WHERE MyMemberField=" & (MyCombo="Yes") , Null)
me.RecordSource = s
```